# AT Commands CMGS return ERROR

Tags: gsm, modem, at-command

I am using Prolink PSH300 HSUPA GSM Modem connect to my laptop and using tera term to test the connect.

First I entered AT it will response me OK

AT 
OK

AT+CMGF=1 
OK

AT+CMGS="+6581XXXXXX" (then I pressed enter error was returned) 
ERROR

Sometime it won't return me error but just hang there no > return.

Could anybody advise me what to do?

Comment: Try sending `AT+CMEE=1` before the `CMGS`. This enables informative error messages (if supported), so you should get something more useful than `ERROR`.

Comment: Actually I did it too, but it just return me error with any error code, sometime it just hang there without any response, but when I typed at <press enter> then OK return.

Answer (score 0):

In your port initialization I would suggest you add these two lines-

```
port.DiscardOutBuffer(); 
port.DiscardInBuffer();
```

These will do a  PurgeComm native WIN32 call, that will be resetting the hardware flow control lines.

Also add `DtrEnable/RtsEnable = true` lines to before opening the port connection.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: My nokia mobile conected to pc over bluetooth link.
commands: at (result ok), at+Cmgf=1(ok), but at+cmgs="mob.no">"hello"ctrl+z (result +cms error 500).  I solved it by making a small change to extra initialisation setting in bluetooth modem. How, i explain here.
conrol panel -> phone and modem -> selected the blue tooth modem -> click properties. In the dialog window that opens goto advance tabs and change the existing extra initialisation commands: from whatever existed to any of the following as mentioned in the website below:
cksaheb.blogspot.in/2011/03/extra-initialization-command-for-gprs.html. My problem for sending sms solved.

Comment: Could you clean up your answer somewhat?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. you must check antena connection.
Your GSM can't fine the network.

Comment: this should be a comment.